# try() in R not continuing execution on exception

Tags: r

I am new to R, and learning it online by trying out some simple code

I read `try()` allows to ignore any error and continue. So I tried this:

[image]

When I put `log()` inside `try()`, I was still getting the same output;

[image]

I was expecting something like:

```
Error in log(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
[1] 10
```

But that `10` is not appearing in the output. Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `source("C:/Mahesh/workspaces/r/temp.r", echo = TRUE)`